# SQL Server Stored Procedure capture return value in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server stored procedure; I need to capture the return value from the stored procedure. Is this the correct way of doing this?

```sql
  declare valback varchar(30)
  set valback = exec storeproc1
```

In this case, `storeproc1` is my stored procedure.

Comment: You need to use `@valback` to indicate it's a variable.

Comment: Does your SP have an OUTPUT parameter that you are trying to retrieve or does your SP perform some kind of insert, update or delete that you just want to check to see if it succeeded?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To start, use proper T-SQL syntax:

```
declare @valback int;
exec @valback = storeproc1;
```

The only return type allowed for a stored procedure is `int`. Stored procedures return status via the [`return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) statement.

I somehow have a feeling that you really want something else, namely:
to have an [OUTPUT parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in the procedure:

```
declare @valback varchar(30);
exec storedproc1 @valback OUTPUT;
```

or capture the procedure result set via `INSERT ... EXEC`. See [How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
DECLARE @valback VARCHAR(30) 
EXEC @valback = storeproc1
```

As per the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx